# python 3.5 not sorting values based on set range using boolean operators

Tags: python, syntax, python-3.5

```
x = y = 0 #sorts the data into spin up or spin down, then in required eV range
for x in range(0,len(BSlist)):
if 'Spin.Up' in BSlist[x]:
    for y in range (x+1,x+(Count)):
        if (float(BSlist[y].split()[1]) >= -2.0) and (float(BSlist[y].split()[1]) <= 2.0):
            UpList1.extend(BSlist[x:(x+(Count))])
            x = ((x // Count) * (Count)) + Count
            continue
if 'Spin.Down' in BSlist[x]:
    for y in range (x+1,x+(Count)):
        if (float(BSlist[y].split()[1]) >= -2.0) and (float(BSlist[y].split()[1]) <= 2.0):
            DnList1.extend(BSlist[x:(x+(Count))])
            x = ((x // Count) * (Count)) + Count
            continue      

UpList2 = []#changing to csv form
x = y = 0
for x in range(0,Count):
UpList2.append(str(x))
if x != 0:
    y = x
    UpList2[x] = UpList2[x] + '\t' + UpList1[x].split()[0] + '\t' + 
UpList1[x].split()[1]
    while y in range(0,len(UpList1)):
        UpList2[x] = UpList2[x] + '\t' + UpList1[y].split()[1]
        y = y + Count
if 'Spin.Up' in UpList1[x]:
    while y in range(0,len(UpList1)):
        UpList2[x] = UpList2[x] + '\t' + UpList1[y][UpList1[y].find('Band'):
(UpList1[y].find('Band')+9)]
        y = y + Count
```

This part of the program takes 60 data points that is previously stored in a list and sorts them into two separate lists. Afterwards, it should go through each of the data points in the lists and check if they are in the range of greater than or equal to -2.0 and less than or equal to 2.0. However, it is only outputting data that is between -2.0 and 8.0. We are wondering if it is a problem with the syntax as it seems as if it is ignoring the second statement of less than or equal to 2.0.

Comment: Could you show a sample of data (contents of `BSlist`)?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LSA1f.png

Here is a link to a picture that shows an example of data that should not be printed into the list. If you look on the right side you see that none of the values are below 2.000... We are trying to exclude this data but it is included in the output.

Comment: So, basically, `BSlist` is a list of strings, each of which contains two floating point numbers, and only the second of those numbers is of interest, right?

Comment: Correct, we are trying to separate those groups of strings based on the seconds set of numbers.

Comment: And the headers (which begin with `#` and contain either `Spin.Up` or `Spin.Down` ) are interspersed in the list every `Count` items, right? This part is not obvious from the picture you gave, but your code seems to rely on that.

Comment: They are the headers of every group of data points. In this case there are 60 data points. We use count to get 62 lines including the header as the list starts at 0.

Answer (score 0):

So, unless I misunderstood the problem (which is quite possible), it boils down to this:

```
for line_num, line in enumerate(BSlist):
    # look for Spin.Up or Spin.Down header
    if 'Spin.Up' in line:
        destination = UpList1
    elif 'Spin.Down' in line:
        destination = DnList1
    else:
        continue

    # header found
    # analyze next Count lines
    series = BSlist[line_num+1:line_num+Count]
    for line2 in series:
        value = float(line2.strip().split()[1])
        if -2.0 <= value <= 2.0:
             destination.append(line)
             destination.extend(series)
             destination.append('\n')
             break
```

Comment: value = float(line2.strip().split()[1])
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Axes(0.125,0.1;0.775x0.8)'

Error Message

Comment: Sorry, looks like I overshoot with the upper range. Now it should work.

Comment: It's still giving the same error,

    value = float(line2.strip().split()[1])
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Axes(0.125,0.1;0.775x0.8)'

Comment: Is `Count` set to 60? And are there exactly 60 data points in each series?

Comment: I define count in the following code.  This makes the program manually find the value for count every time.

with open("test.txt", "r") as fh: #finds Count (the number of lines of data) for one band.
    Count = 0
    for line in fh:
        if line == '\n':
            break
        Count += 1

Comment: And are you sure all series are the same length? I suspect it is not the case.

Comment: Yes they are, each one contains 62 data points including the header.

Comment: You didn't mention empty lines. That's the problem with showing a picture rather than actual data. Try setting `Count` to 60.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't send the data as it was too large for the comment. With Count, we want it to be flexible, not connected to a single value. So basically for every line, count adds one to itself and when it hits an empty line it stops counting. So every time you go through a group of data, count becomes 62.

Comment: One more thing I am not sure I got right: assuming there are some data outside the (-2; 2) range in a series, do you want just those items filtered out, or the whole series?

Comment: If there is one data point that is inside the 2;-2 range, the entire series has to be included. If no data points are in the range the entire series is discarded.

Comment: Every other time you run the code, it returns an error message.

    UpList2[x] = UpList2[x] + '\t' + UpList1[y].split()[1]
IndexError: list index out of range

That is the error. That code is part of the code that changes this data into a csv format.

Comment: I give up then.

Comment: UpList2 is declared empty at the beginning of this code so we are opening a new list to re organize the data.

Comment: Oh, no! I think it is a problem with the syntax compatibility of the two parts of the program.

Comment: I added that part of the code to the question if you would like to look at it.